# Populating JTable from ArrayList

Tags: java, database, swing, arraylist, jtable

This function returns `ArrayList` that contains some data from DB:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> executeQuery(String host, String database,
            String sqlStatement)
```

I need to populate `JTable` with this `ArrayList`. For instance, one of possible outputs could be (3 rows, 4 columns):

```
[[1, 10, 1, 2], [2, 11, 2, 1], [3, 12, 3, 1]]
```

I know that a table model should be created, but what if the columns are not known prior?

Comment: you can set a new table model if you need, or you could add a Column (see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the methods of [`DatabaseMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) to find the number and names of a table's attributes. You can use [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) to populate your data structure dynamically. Also consider programming to the interface, e.g `List<List<Number>>` or `List<List<Integer>>`.